# How do I limit the acceptable values in a database column to be 1 to 5?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table in a database where one of the columns should have a value from 1 to 5.  How can I write this limitation into the database?  Do I use a constraint?  What's the best practice say about this kind of thing?

I am using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add a constraint to your table, better a named one:

```
ALTER TABLE YourSchema.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_YourTable_YourColumn_ValidLimits
CHECK(YourColumn BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
```

In your CREATE TABLE statement, do this:

```
CREATE TABLE YourSchema.YourTable(YourColumn INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_YourTable_YourColumn_ValidLimits
CHECK(YourColumn BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
SomeOtherColumns VARCHAR(10)
);
```

The best practice is to explicitly name your constraints.

Comment: I code it: **MyColumn>= 1 AND MyColumn<=5)** so there would be no confusion if end points are included or not

Comment: @KM: If you subsequently script the CK out using SSMS, it should change the BETWEEN to this anyway. It also changes IN to OR too.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to add this during your table creation, you could do it as follows...

```
create table MyTable
    (MyColumn tinyint CONSTRAINT MyColumn_CheckLimit CHECK (MyColumn BETWEEN 1 AND 5))
```